# Would or will - in a somewhat hypothetical situation

Tags: will-would

> At (my old company) I made translations on a daily basis. Thus, my experience in 
>   translation will help me to ensure timely provision of translated materials.

This is from a cover letter I'm sending. Since getting this job (and the second sentence) is a hypothetical situation, "would" seems appropriate, if I understand the rules correctly. However, "will" just sounds better to me. Which one is correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your experience will help you in any job that requires translation, not just the one you are applying for. So I think you can justify "will", which sounds better, in my ears, as being more positive and less tentative.

I remember once interviewing a prospective advisor. The interview had not gone well, and he knew it. His final remarks were "We would be able to help you, if you were to decide to employ us."

In your case, you would have to say "would" if you wanted to specify that your experience was relevant to that employer's particular tasks in the job you are applying for.

Comment: An afterthought: you could even justify "Thus, my experience in translation helps me to ensure timely provision of translated materials", because your experience is helping you now.